# How to run wireshark on the background without the GUI?

Tags: macos, wireshark

I am trying to run Wireshark on Mac OS X, on the background. I did install the command line utilities, and so I am able to start wireshark and capture packet using the command line. The only thing I want now is to run it on the background, without even having the X11 icon on the task bar and see the window of wireshark. I believe it is possible but can't find anything on the doc of Wireshark.

Maybe another way would be to find a trick to hide an icon on Mac OS X...

If anybody already did that or have an idea...

Thank you

Please excuse my English which is not perfect at all

Comment: This is a question for superuser.com

Comment: Or possibly for apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's too old to migrate, but I would certainly answer this on https://apple.stackexchange.com - you can install both Wireshark and the command line tools from https://brew.sh home-brew package system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I remember TShark comes with all distributions of Wireshark. This runs from the command line.
The documentation for it is [tshark documentation](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html)

And there's some examples on how to use it [here](https://hackertarget.com/tshark-tutorial-and-filter-examples/)

Comment: I can vouch for its presence with the wireshark that Fink installed for me.